# How to implement a semicolon ends the input in C++?

Tags: c++

How to implement a command line interface, the command must end with semicolon. Then press enter to execute. Otherwise, press enter wraps the line. If I don't descirbe it clearly, you can refer to the mysql command line.

How to implement the above in C++? For example:

If user inputs `foo;bar` then `str = "foo"`. It can have some spaces in between `;`.

In C++ IO I just know:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
 string str;
 cin >> str;
}
```

I don't know how to implement other input function.

Comment: if user types `foo;bar` then contents of `str` should be `foo` ? Please include input, output and expected output ni the question

Comment: [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and parse yourself the content?

Comment: Yes. if user types foo; bar, the str should be foo.I add this to my question. thank you

Comment: @Jarod42. Thank you, I forget that function in c++

Comment: Read about [recursive descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser). Consider using [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) or [ANTLR](http://antlr.org/)

Answer (score 2):

The most simple approach would be to use [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) (as adviced in comments), but with a custom delimiter (`';'` in your case) like this:

```cpp
string command;
while (getline(cin, command, ';')) {
    // process the command there
}
```

However, this approach has several drawbacks and is pretty limited:

- it reads until any `';'` is hit. If you're going to process commands complicated enough to support string literals, then you will need more complicated parsing to handle this: `echo "Hello; sample text"; exit;`, as two commands, but not three;
- when you hit Enter, `getline` will wait for more input until it sees a semicolon, but it will not insert any 'user-friendly' prompt like `>`  to let the user know that they need to supply more input or that they forgot the semicolon at the end of command.

If you're ok to go without supporting these features, `getline` is quite good to go. Otherwise you'll need to parse your input lines by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want to do:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
   std::string command;
   bool flag = true;
   do
   {
      std::string str;
      std::getline(std::cin,str);
      for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
      {
          if(str[i] == ';')
          {
               str = str.substr(0,i+1);
               flag = false;
          }
      }
      command += str;
   } while(flag);
}
```